# No sound on headphones on an Asus k50ij

Tags: 11.10, sound, asus

I've tried [the solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1762969) from 11.04 however it doesn't seems to work. No matter what do I mute or unmute.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it one minute ago, try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install alsa-hda-dkms
```

then reboot or

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

sorry if too late