# Trusty headphone sound very low

Tags: 14.04, sound, headphones

I know this has been asked a couple of times, but none of the solutions I've found work for me. I bought a lenovo G700 laptop a few days ago and installed Ubuntu 14.04.

I'm quite experienced with linux, but not with alsa and pulse and whatnot. So the problem is the following, my sound worked perfectly fine, until today.

I plugged in my headphones and almost no sound comes out. I played some metal songs and then noticed that there actually is sounds, just very very quiet and a bit distorted. After pulling out the headphones the speakers continue to work just fine, only the jack output isn't working.

I tried rebooting (duh), reinstalling alsa and pulse, maximizing every single volume slider I've found - both gui and in the terminal (I ran alsamixer and checked if something was muted, but it wasn't).

I'm running out of options and I don't feel like reinstalling, since I've spent the last 3 days installing needed packages and setting up configs and everything.

Does anybody have an idea what could be causing it? I don't remember installing any package that could conflict with sound.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Have you read [this Q/A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/153898/no-sound-with-headphones-but-sound-with-stereo?rq=1)?

Comment: The problem is that there is sound, just extremely quiet. Thus, the driver is working, only some config or something is messsed up